# select from linq statement with await

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, async-await

This seems like it should be very simple, I have the following code

```
var additionalInformation=   response.AdditionalInformation.Select( async x =>  new AdditionalInformationItem
                {
                    StatementCode = x?.StatementCode?.Value,
                    LimitDateTime = x?.LimitDateTime?.Item?.Value,
                    StatementTypeCode = x?.StatementTypeCode?.Value,
                    StatementDescription = x?.StatementDescription?.Value,
                    AdditionalInformationResult = await BuildAdditionalInformationPointers(x)


                }).ToList();
```

What I am trying to achieve is for additionalInformation to be of type

```
List<AdditionalInformationItem>
```

, what I am getting is `List<Task<AdditionalInformationItem>>`

Can anyone help me correctly reformulate my statement?

Comment: why a async lambda? any specific reason? If you want parallel Linq then use the same probably

Comment: @Rahul, because it is calling an async function BuildAdditionalInformationPointers()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to unwrap the tasks using, `await Task.WhenAll(additionalInformation)` then you access the actual result using `additionalInformation[0].Result`.

So something like this:

```
var additionalInformation=   response.AdditionalInformation.Select( async x =>  new AdditionalInformationItem
                {
                    StatementCode = x?.StatementCode?.Value,
                    LimitDateTime = x?.LimitDateTime?.Item?.Value,
                    StatementTypeCode = x?.StatementTypeCode?.Value,
                    StatementDescription = x?.StatementDescription?.Value,
                    AdditionalInformationResult = await BuildAdditionalInformationPointers(x)


                });

await Task.WhenAll(additionalInformation);
//This will iterate the results so may not be the most efficient method if you have a lot of results
List<AdditionalInformationItem> unwrapped = additionalInformation.Select(s => s.Result).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is actually no way to do this in a simple lambda expression. The async lambda expression will always return a `Task<T>`. So you can go quick and dirty and call `.Result` on the `Task` (don't do it! Except if you await first as in Liam's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56749493/3883866)), or simply initialize a new list and add items in a foreach loop:

```
var additionalInformation = new List<AdditionalInformationItem>();
foreach (var x in response.AdditionalInformation)
{
    var item = new AdditionalInformationItem
        {
            StatementCode = x?.StatementCode?.Value,
            LimitDateTime = x?.LimitDateTime?.Item?.Value,
            StatementTypeCode = x?.StatementTypeCode?.Value,
            StatementDescription = x?.StatementDescription?.Value,
            AdditionalInformationResult = await BuildAdditionalInformationPointers(x)
        };

    additionalInformation.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: It's perfectly fine to access `.Result` provided you have awaited the async call. The only time this is a bad idea is if you haven't waited for the async call to complete, then this can cause deadlocks

Comment: @Liam You are right, as illustrated brightly in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

`await Task.WhenAll` will automatically unwrap the tasks, and will hand you an array with the results.

```
AdditionalInformationItem[] additionalInformation = await Task.WhenAll(
    response.AdditionalInformation.Select(async x => new AdditionalInformationItem
    {
        StatementCode = x?.StatementCode?.Value,
        LimitDateTime = x?.LimitDateTime?.Item?.Value,
        StatementTypeCode = x?.StatementTypeCode?.Value,
        StatementDescription = x?.StatementDescription?.Value,
        AdditionalInformationResult = await BuildAdditionalInformationPointers(x)
    });
);
```